# NotificationManagerCompat takes too long to update enabled listener packages

Tags: android, notifications

**Question:** There is another way of checking notification access that is more accurate than using `NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages()`?

**Explanation of what is happening with my code:**

In my app there is a service to read notifications, so it verifies if have or not permission to do so in its initialization method.

The problem is the code that verifies this permission is returning `false` right after I granted access to notifications (the `init()` is called on `onListenerConnected()` that is a method of `NotificationListenerService`, and inside `init()` there is a `hasPermission()` that is messing my app up).

The `hasPermission()` was pretty simple, but to investigate I made a few adaptations:

```java
class PermissionsManager {
    // ...
    public static boolean hasPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean permission = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            permission = NotificationManagerCompat
                    .getEnabledListenerPackages(context)
                    .contains(context.getPackageName());
            Log.d(TAG, "permission to access notifications: " + (permission ? "granted" : "denied"));
            if (permission) break;
        }

        return permission;
    }
}
```

and then I realize that the `NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPakcages()` just was not updating fast enough:

```
01-23 09:45:39.008 I/chatty: uid=10251 com.example.app:notifications identical 5 lines
01-23 09:45:39.008 D/PermissionsManager: permission to access notifications: denied
01-23 09:45:39.009 D/PermissionsManager: permission to access notifications: denied
01-23 09:45:39.009 I/chatty: uid=10251 com.example.app:notifications identical 5 lines
01-23 09:45:39.010 D/PermissionsManager: permission to access notifications: denied
01-23 09:45:39.011 D/PermissionsManager: permission to access notifications: granted
```

Previously I used the following code to acquire the permission, but it has the same result:

```java
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, CustomNotificationListenerService.class);
String flat = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
return flat != null && flat.contains(cn.flattenToString());
```